# Open txt file as a Microsoft Excel Comma Separated Values File (.csv)

Tags: vb.net

I have a test machine that I use at work that outputs data in a large txt file (the data is already separated by commas) and I am trying to make a vb.net app to open the txt as a csv. Then to place the data in graphs in an excel template I made. I already have code that searches a designated folder for the test using a combobox but I am stuck on the next step. Opening a txt as a csv.

Code:

```
Public Class RF_Data_AutoFormat
Private Sub cbo_FileList_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbo_FileList.Click
    Dim dir = "C:\Users\aholiday\Desktop\Data Dump"
    cbo_FileList.Items.Clear()
    For Each file As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir)
        cbo_FileList.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file))
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub btn_Do_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Do.Click
    Dim FileTXT
    cbo_FileList.Text = FileTXT
    FileOpen()??????

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: CSV files *are* text files.  It is how you handle the contents that is different.

Comment: If I save a txt with the extension csv it saves it as a Microsoft Excel Comma Separated Values File (.csv). Im trying to automat the process instead of doing it one by one

Comment: Are you wanting Excel to open it?

Comment: sure, that's what It does now. one by one and it works so far. Just tedious.

Comment: You just need to rename it: `System.IO.File.Move("filename.txt", "filename.csv")`

Comment: Tim, What you gave me follows the wrong file file path. Should follow `C:\Users\aholiday\Desktop\Data Dump` it is trying to find the file in ``C:\Users\aholiday\Desktop\Visual Studios Projects\RF Data AutoFormat\RF Data AutoFormat\bin\Debug\``

Comment: ok I think I got it. I used ` File.Move(txtpath, csvpath) ` after I declared and assigned what ``txtpath`` and ```csvpath ```are. Thanks for the suggestion Tim

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I got it. I used `File.Move(txtpath, csvpath)` after I declared and assigned what `txtpath` and `csvpath` are. Thanks for the suggestion Tim

Code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Public Class Form1
Private Sub cbo_FileList_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbo_FileList.Click
    Dim folderpath = "C:\Users\aholiday\Desktop\Data Dump"
    cbo_FileList.Items.Clear()
    For Each file As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(folderpath)
        cbo_FileList.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file))
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub btn_Do_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Do.Click
    Dim txtpath As String
    Dim csvpath As String = "C:\Temp"
    Dim FileTXT As String
    Dim folderpath As String

    folderpath = "C:\Users\aholiday\Desktop\Data Dump"
    FileTXT = cbo_FileList.Text
    csvpath = "C:\Temp\" & FileTXT & ".csv"
    txtpath = folderpath & "\" & FileTXT & ".txt"

    File.Move(txtpath, csvpath)

End Sub
End Class
```